# Frobenius between $\mathbb{Z}_p[p^{1/p^m}]$-modules etale

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

The questions are motivated by P. Scholze's answer in MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132438/why-is-faltings-almost-purity-theorem-a-purity-theorem. Consider for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p$ prime the rings $$A_m = \mathbb{Z}_p[p^{1/p^m},T^{\pm 1/p^m}]$$

Each $A_m$ is a $R_m:= \mathbb{Z}_p[p^{1/p^m}]$-algebra given by canonical inclusion $$i_m:\mathbb{Z}_p[p^{1/p^m}] \to \mathbb{Z}_p[p^{1/p^m},T^{\pm 1/p^m}]$$

We can also endow the $R_m$ with transition maps $t_{mn}: R_m \to R_n$ for $m >n$ induced by iterations of the canonical inclusions:

$$t_{m,m+1}: \mathbb{Z}_p[p^{1/p^{m}},T^{\pm 1/p^{m}}] \to \mathbb{Z}_p[p^{1/p^{m+1}},T^{\pm 1/p^{m+1}}]$$

I have some questions about the properties of $i_m$ and $t_{mn}$.

**Question I** Why is $i_m$ is a **smooth** ring map? What might be the most elegant/ conventional/standard way to show smoothness of $i_m$ in this question?

One criterion for smoothness I'm familar with is that a morphism of schemes $f: X \to Y$ is smooth iff it is flat and all geometric fibers are smooth.

That's a very general criterion working for arbitrary schemes. Here $i_m$ induce a morphism $\operatorname{Spec} \ A_m \to \operatorname{Spec} R_m$ between affine schemes, so I hope that in this case there is a more "simple" way to show smoothness without passing explicitely to the $\operatorname{Spec}$ structure and for example not to talking about geometric fibers?

In my searching I found in Stacks this: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00T1 They are working with the concept of cotangent complex and the criterion/definition Definition 10.136.1 requiring to check quasi-isomorpism looks not really more accesible than the criterion above.

**Question II:** Why the transition maps  $t_{m+1,m}$ are etale after inverting $p$? ie when we invert $p$ in $R_m$ or localize $R_m$ at $p$ we obtain $(R_m)_p:=\mathbb{Z}_p[p^{ \pm 1/p^m},T^{\pm 1/p^m}]$, right?

So the question boils down why is the induced Frobenius $$(t_{m,m+1})_p: (R_{m})_p \to (R_{m+1})_p$$

etale? One criterion for etaleness (that I know) is flat and unramified.

On flatness I have no idea, on ramification we have to show that the **discriminant ideal** becomes unit ideal after interting $p$. The proplem is I haven't here an ideal how to calculate the discriminant ideal of $R_m$.

Comment: sorry, I mean indeed $p^{1/p^{m+1}} \mapsto (p^{1/p^{m+1}})^p$

Comment: No, no morphism does $p^a \to p^{ap}$.

Comment: I think I see the problem. Do you see then which "transition maps" Scholze meant in the original source? He not explicitly described them, thus I assumed something "canonical"...

Comment: Looking at the MO post I think it is about the ramification of the embedding $A_m=\Bbb{Z}_p[p^{1/p^m}, T^{1/p^m}] \to A_{m+1}= \Bbb{Z}_p[p^{1/p^{m+1}}, T^{1/p^{m+1}}]$, the ramified primes (of the extension $A_{m+1}/A_m$) are contained in the maximal ideal $(p^{1/p^m}, T^{1/p^m})$ so inverting $p$ and $T$ gives a tower of etale extensions $A_\infty[p^{-1},T^{-1}]/A_0[p^{-1},T^{-1}]$. The smoothness is more or less the same as that $\Bbb{A}^1$ is a smooth curve.

Comment: Why are all ramified primes contained in $(p^{1/p^m}, T^{1/p^m})$?

Comment: @reuns: I think one criterion which I know to check where the embedding $A_m \to A_{m+1}$ is ramified is to take a prime $\mathfrak{p} \subset A_{m+1}$ and a prime $\mathfrak{q} \subset A_{m}$ lying over $\mathfrak{p} $ wrt this embedding and consider the induced map betweenlocalizations $(A_m)_{\mathfrak{q}} \to (A_{m+1})_{\mathfrak{p} }$. Then $\mathfrak{q} $ is not ramified iff induced field extension $(A_m)_{\mathfrak{q}}/\mathfrak{q} \to (A_{m+1})_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}$ is separable and $\mathfrak{q}A_{m+1}=\mathfrak{p}A_{m+1}$ (in general only the inclusion "$\subset$" holds.

Comment: This method always works but sometimes too circumstaneous. Here in the setting of this question: why is it more or less "obvious" that all ramified primes contained in $(p^{1/p^m}, T^{1/p^m})$. Do you just refer to the criterion I explaned in the comment before or do you use here another criterion making it "easier" to check here what are the ramified primes in the given setting?

Comment: It is ramified at $(p^{1/p^m})$ and $(T^{1/p^m})$, invert $p,T$ and see the obtained extension is unramified

Comment: and why is it obvious that the inclusion isn't ramified at other primes?